# "ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<project>.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it" recieved when attempting to runserver

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I have created a simple webapp with django to display some lists from a .csv file. This program works perfectly fine on my local machine using runserver, however, when attempting to deploy using DigitalOcean using the following guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file , when I run ~//manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 I am greeted with a

TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

followed by

"ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf .urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import."

After spending the day searching around the majority of other people with this problem have spelling mistakes or missing commas however I don't THINK that's the case for me. I've shown my url files below:

urls.py - project

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('recommendation/', include('recommendation.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

urls.py - recommendation

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'recommendation'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^movie/search', views.movie, name='movie'),
]
```

I saw a post explaining that the 'module' object was being found due to urlpatterns not being properly defined as lists (missing commas).

Any help is much appreciated, thanks for your time and any advice

EDIT: Image of traceback

[screencap of traceback from putty terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuZoA.png)

EDIT 2: To give an idea of how mmy views and "engine" file operate in terms of imports and functions:

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import engine as eng
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import json

def index(request):
    lom = eng.movielist
    return render(request, 'recommendation/index.html', {'lom':lom})

@csrf_exempt
def movie(request):
    handles GET requests, returns a list of movie info + youtube trailers
```

engine.py

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
from ast import literal_eval
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

//the code for processing a movie choice and returning a list of recommendatioons
```

**FINAL EDIT:** the problem was that I didnt have sklearn installed on my server...whoops

Comment: @shubwub   I think Problem is with the use of both `path` and  `url` in your urls.py
either use `path` or use `url` based on your django version

Comment: @Pankaj78691 - no, that's not the issue, mixing `path()` and `url()` is possible.

Comment: Perhaps there's something wrong in your `views.py`. Does `runserver` work if you comment out `path('recommendation/', include('recommendation.urls')),`?

Comment: Yeah swapping both urls to path/url doesnt change anything but removing the line you specified at least runs the server. Is it worth posting my views layout too?

Comment: if removing `path('recommendation/', include('recommendation.urls'))` works then  you need to check for the circular imports in your code

Comment: I've added the imports used for views and my recommendation engine as well as the declarations for my views

Comment: Try running `./manage.py shell`, and then `from recommendation import views` to see if importing the views causes an error.

Comment: This returns a "No module named sklearn" from line 3 of my engine.py

Comment: That suggests you haven't installed `sklearn` on your digital ocean machine.

Comment: After installing sklearn your import views statement runs without error and when attempting 'runserver 0.0.0.0:8000' again it now says no module named 'recommendation' on line 20 of urls.py. 
Also wanted to say thanks for the help so far I appreciate it

Comment: ...I'd spelt recommendation wrong in my urls.py when i rewrote it after removing the path to check for circular imports, but it finally works now, thank you SO much

Comment: Glad you figured out the problem :)